# Using OpenXML to pass in multiple params to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-openxml

Is there a way to use OpenXML with a SQL Server stored procedure to pass in multiple parameters without using a temp table (which has really been slowing us down?)?

For example, with a single parameter:

```
exec usp_FooBar 
'<Data><States><State StateID="16" StateName="Massachusetts" "/></States></Data>'
```

In `usp_FooBar` I'd get the `StateID` value by

```
Declare @StateID int
.
.
.

 SELECT @StateID = StateID FROM  
  OPENXML(@IDOC,'/Data/States/State',1)   
  WITH      
  (      
   StateID INT    
  )
```

However, lets say I want to pass in multiple states:

```
exec usp_FooBar 
'<Data><States><State StateID="16" StateName="Massachusetts" "/><State StateID="87" StateName="Minnesota" /></States></Data>'
```

Is there any way I can do something similar to the single state scenario, where I can accept any arbitrary number of parameters, without using temp tables (which as I've mentioned, have taken a significant hit on performance for me)?

Comment: I think temp tables is the fastest way, here is a good article about all solutions: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: I would recommend to ditch `OpenXML` and use the **native** XQuery support instead - and yes, you can definitely do this, no problem

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
Declare @XML xml = '
<Data>
    <States>
        <State StateID="16" StateName="Massachusetts" />
        <State StateID="25" StateName="New York" />
        <State StateID="13" StateName="Rhode Island" />
    </States>
</Data>
'


Select Grp    = r.value('@StateID','int')
      ,Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 From  @XML.nodes('/Data/States/State') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
```

**Returns**

```
Grp Item        Value
16  StateID     16
16  StateName   Massachusetts
25  StateID     25
25  StateName   New York
13  StateID     13
13  StateName   Rhode Island
```

Comment: @Amanda_Panda Sorry, had a quick call.  I added a GRP column to isolate the nodes.  This can be a row_number as a more generic item